# html2canvas not renderig svg (chartist line)

Tags: svg, html2canvas, chartist.js, canvg

I am using chartist to take a screenshot of my page which contains a chart line and save it to the server, the page is displayed correctly but the chart is not rendered. I did some research before posting my issue and understood that html2canvas does not work with svg and that I should convert the svg tag to img using canvg then take my screenshot but none of the answers worked for me .

the code I'm using:

```
function exportAndSaveCanvas()  {

                    html2canvas($("#captures"), { 
                        allowTaint: true,
                    background:'#fff',
                    onrendered: function(canvas) {         
                    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');  

                    var code_firme = $("input[name=code_firme]").val();
                    var id_user = $("input[name=id_user]").val();
                    var page = '1';

                    var url = "{{path('uploadPdfImages')}}";
                        $.ajax({ 
                            type: "POST", 
                            url: url,
                            dataType: 'text',
                            data: {
                                base64data : imgData
                            }
                        });     
                    }
                    });
                }
```

i call this action after chart creation using :

```
chart.on('created', function(data){
         setTimeout(exportAndSaveCanvas(), 13000);
         });
```

html view :

[html view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9fZ9.jpg)

[svg tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlBLf.jpg)

results:

[screenshot view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SvKj.jpg)

Has anyone successfully converted a Chartist chart line to an image?

Comment: Have you found a solution? Stock at the same issue

Comment: I used chart.js  instead of chartist.js